# Specialized or Specialist

Tags: adjectives

There is a large hospital in my city whose name is ***King Fahd Specialist Hospital***. I argued with a doctor working there about the name of the hospital. I said that it needs to be changed into ***King Fahd Specialized Hospital***. But he argued that the use of the adjective ***specialist*** refers to the specialist doctors working there. To me, ***specialized*** is more accurate because it modifies the noun hospital. Am l correct?

Comment: I would go with "Specialist".

Comment: I am in a tight spot.

Comment: If all the doctors were removed and the building were up for sale, could the building itself still be recognized as being specialized in some way?

Comment: No, it couldn't

Comment: Respected dictionaries should be the first port of call. [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/specialist) gives the appropriate sense: '**specialist**: dealing with one [(or a few)] particular subject/s, product/s, or area/s of activity more than with others'. Next, Google ngrams: checking in depth, both are used, but there are quite a lot of false positives (often prenominal) for 'specialized hospital'. So either is available, but I'd say 'specialist hospital / school / college ...' are the more normal choices.

Comment: @Edwin: You're right. It seems that l should have checked in depth before posting the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you are not correct. Doctors at the cited hospital practice various distinct specialties, instead of being merely "hospitalists" or "general/family practitioners". Were they to all practice the *same* specialty then and only then should the name be "specialized hospital".

Comment: Surely a hospital can specialise in several areas?